Infinite closed subgroup of ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}[[T]])$ with full residual image
Let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite field of order $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers and $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[T]]$ be the ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. For $p\geq 5$, Serre proved that if $G$ is a closed subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ such that its mod $p$ residual image in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ contains ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, then $G$ contains ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.  My question is the following:

Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}[[T]])$ where $n\geq 2$. Suppose that $G$ is infinite and its mod $T$ residual image is ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$. Is it true that $G$ is an open subgroup of ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}[[T]])$?


What about $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p[[T^2]])$?

thanks for your counter example.

Take any $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and add any congruence subgroup, if I am not confusing myself, you should get another counter example.
